# how to get checked checkbox values and selected dropdown value using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Below i have added my code here i want to get if i press submit button how to get checked check box values and selected drop down value.here checked check box values i am getting but if i select some offer in drop down .for example i checked Samsung Galaxy S6 and we have one offer for Samsung Galaxy S6 i have selected 20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6 in drop down.when i submit the submit button i need checked check box values and selected offer(20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6) id .pls some one help me out [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/7/)

```js
function Test1Controller($scope) {
  var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
    var serverData = ["Samsung Galaxy Note", "Samsung Galaxy S6", "Samsung Galaxy Avant","Samsung Galaxy Young"];
    $scope.items= [] ;

    for(var i=0;i<serverData.length;i++)
    {
        var modal = {
        name:serverData[i],
        selected:false
        };        
        $scope.items.push(modal);        
    }
    //----------------------------Our Shop Offers----------------------------------------
    $scope.offers = [
    {
        id: "as23456",
        Store: "samsung",
        Offer_message:"1500rs off",
        modalname: "Samsung Galaxy Young"       

    },{
        id: "de34575",
        Store: "samsung",
        Offer_message:"20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6",
        modalname: "Samsung Galaxy S6"       

    },
    ]
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     $scope.check = function()
  
     {
  
  
         var checkedItems = [];
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++)
            {
                  if($scope.items[i].selected){
                      checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
                    }
            }
              console.log(checkedItems) ; 
     }
$scope.selection = [];

      $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(item) {
$scope.gotOffers=[];
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(item);

      // is currently selected
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      // is newly selected
      else {
        $scope.selection.push(item);
      }

        for(var i=0;i<$scope.selection.length;i++){
          for(var j=0;j<$scope.offers.length;j++){
            console.log($scope.selection[i].name  +"   "+ $scope.offers[j].modalname)
            if( $scope.selection[i].name  == $scope.offers[j].modalname){
              var idx = $scope.gotOffers.indexOf($scope.offers[j].Offer_message);
              if(idx == -1){
                console.log("inside idx")
                $scope.gotOffers.push($scope.offers[j].Offer_message);
              }

            }
          }

        }
  console.log($scope.offers);
  
    };


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Test1Controller" >
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"  ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)"/> {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <select ng-show="gotOffers.length > 0" >
      <option ng-repeat="offer in gotOffers" ng-model="offer"  value="offer">{{offer}}</option>
    </select>

      <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `ng-model` on select, hence you were not able to use it. Also I have updated your code to fit `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` on *option*.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0heruyep/6/)

#### Code

```js
function Test1Controller($scope) {
  var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
  var serverData = ["Samsung Galaxy Note", "Samsung Galaxy S6", "Samsung Galaxy Avant", "Samsung Galaxy Young"];
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.selectedOffer = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
    var modal = {
      name: serverData[i],
      selected: false,
    };
    $scope.items.push(modal);
  }
  //----------------------------Our Shop Offers----------------------------------------
  $scope.offers = [{
      id: "as23456",
      Store: "samsung",
      Offer_message: "1500rs off",
      modalname: "Samsung Galaxy Young"
    }, {
      id: "de34575",
      Store: "samsung",
      Offer_message: "20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6",
      modalname: "Samsung Galaxy S6"
    }, ]
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $scope.check = function() {
    var checkedItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.items[i].selected == true) {
        checkedItems.push({
          name: $scope.items[i].name,
          offer: $scope.selectedOffer.Offer_message
        });
      }
    }

    console.log(checkedItems)

    $scope.validOffers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
      var checkedModel = checkedItems[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < $scope.offers.length; j++) {
        if ($scope.offers[j].modalname == checkedModel.name) {
          $scope.validOffers.push($scope.offers[j]);
        }
      }
    }

    if ($scope.validOffers.length > 0) {
      $scope.validOffers.unshift({
        id: "0",
        Store: $scope.validOffers[0].Store,
        Offer_message: "Please Select Offer",
        modalname: $scope.validOffers[0].modalname,
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Test1Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input ng-click="check()" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" /> {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <div>
      <select ng-show="validOffers.length > 0" ng-model="selectedOffer" ng-options="offer.Offer_message for offer in validOffers">
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can user select more than one offer? If I select *S6* and *Young*, I get only one select.

Comment: if user select Samsung Galaxy S6,Samsung Galaxy Young .in drop down user will get two offers but user can select only one in dropdown

Comment: Then you do not need an array. A simple variable to override value should be enough and if unchecked, reset the value, but unlike my code above, store entire object and compare modalname to reset and it should do the trick.